# Using Powershell to export big output from Oracle to CSV

Tags: oracle, powershell, csv, export-to-csv

I need to export an quite a big CSV file from Oracle once a week.

I tried two approaches.

1. Adapter.fill(dataset)
2. Looping through columns and rows to save into a CSV file one line at a time.

The first one is running out of memory when running (the server machine has only 4 GB of RAM), the second one takes about an hour as there are over 4 milion rows to export.

Here's code #1:

```
#Your query. It cannot contain any double quotes otherwise it will break.
$query = "SELECT manycolumns FROM somequery"

#Oracle login credentials and other variables
$username = "username"
$password = "password"
$datasource = "database address"
$output = "\\NetworkLocation\Sales.csv"

#creates a blank CSV file and make sure it's in ASCI
Out-File $output -Force ascii

#This here will look for "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll" file inside "C:\Oracle" folder. We usually have two versions of Oracle installed so the adaptor can be in different locations. Needs changing if the Oracle is installed elsewhere.
$location = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Oracle -Filter Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force

#Establishes connection to Oracle using the DLL file
Add-Type -Path $location.FullName
$connectionString = 'User Id=' + $username + ';Password=' + $password + ';Data Source=' + $datasource
$connection = New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection($connectionString)
$connection.open()
$command=$connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText=$query

#Creates a table in memory and fills it with results from the query. Then, export the virtual table into CSV.
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$Adapter = New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter($command)
$Adapter.Fill($DataSet)
$DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-Csv $output -NoTypeInformation

$connection.Close()
```

And here's #2

```
#Your query. It cannot contain any double quotes otherwise it will break.
$query = "SELECT manycolumns FROM somequery"

#Oracle login credentials and other variables
$username = "username"
$password = "password"
$datasource = "database address"
$output = "\\NetworkLocation\Sales.csv"
$tempfile = $env:TEMP + "\Temp.csv"

#creates a blank CSV file and make sure it's in ASCI
Out-File $tempfile -Force ascii

#This here will look for "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll" file inside "C:\Oracle" folder. Needs changing if the Oracle is installed elsewhere.
$location = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Oracle -Filter Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force

#Establishes connection to Oracle using the DLL file
Add-Type -Path $location.FullName
$connectionString = 'User Id=' + $username + ';Password=' + $password + ';Data Source=' + $datasource
$connection = New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection($connectionString)
$connection.open()
$command=$connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText=$query

#Reads results column by column. This way you don't have to specify how many columns it has.
$reader = $command.ExecuteReader()
  while($reader.Read()) {
       $props = @{}
       for($i = 0; $i -lt $reader.FieldCount; $i+=1) {
           $name = $reader.GetName($i)
           $value = $reader.item($i)
           $props.Add($name, $value)   
       }
       #Exports each line to CSV file. Works best when the file is on local drive as it saves it after each line.
       new-object PSObject -Property $props | Export-Csv $tempfile -NoTypeInformation -Append
  }

Move-Item $tempfile $output -Force

$connection.Close()
```

Ideally, I would like to use the first code as it is way faster than the second one but to somehow avoid running out of memory.

Do you guys and gals know if there's some way to "fill" first 1 milion records, append them to CSV, clean the "DataSet" table, next 1 milion etc? After the code finishes running the CSV weights ~1.3 GB but when it runs, even 8 GB of Memory is not enough for it (my laptop has 8 but server only has 4 GB and it really hits it hard).

Any tips will be appreciated.

Comment: How about telling [Oracle itself](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:88212348059) to [create a CSV](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9536328100346697722) file? That would perform much better, as the DB engine would do all the heavy lifting locally.

Comment: Do you need "admin" rights on the Oracle in order to do that? My team only have a "Read" access as the database is owned and updated by a 3rd party company that we pay a lot of money just to make a simple change.

Comment: Oracle permissions questions would be better on-topic at [DBA.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com). Consider posting a whole new question there about how to do a CSV export and maybe about best practices for those.

Comment: I don't have any questions about permissions. I just want to export a result of a query into a 1.3 GB CSV file once a week using a windows scheduler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the responses, I learned about Oracle scripts and sql*plus that I never knew existed. I probably will use them in the future but I guess I will have to update my Oracle Developer package.

I have found a way to edit my code to work using the documentation here:
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/OracleDataAdapterClass.htm#i1002865

It's not perfect as it pauses every 1 milion rows, saves the output and re-run the query which re-evaluates it (the one I'm running takes about 1-2 minutes to evaluate).

It's basically the same as running one code x times (where x is a ceiling of number of rows in milions) doing "fetch first 1'000'000 rows only" then "Offset 1'000'00 rows Fetch next 1'000'000 rows only" etc. and saving it into CSV appending at the bottom.

Here's the code:

```
#Your query. It cannot contain any double quotes otherwise it will break.
$query = "SELECT
A lot of columns
FROM
a lot of tables joined together
WHERE
a lot of conditions
"

#Oracle login credentials and other variables
$username = myusername
$password = mypassword
$datasource = TNSnameofmyDatasource
$output = "$env:USERPROFILE\desktop\Sales.csv"

#creates a blank CSV file and make sure it's in ASCII as that's what the output of my query is
Out-File $output -Force ascii

#This here will look for "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll" file inside "C:\Oracle" folder. Needs changing if the Oracle is installed elsewhere.
$location = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Oracle -Filter Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force

#Establishes connection to Oracle using the DLL file
Add-Type -Path $location.FullName
$connectionString = 'User Id=' + $username + ';Password=' + $password + ';Data Source=' + $datasource
$connection = New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection($connectionString)
$connection.open()
$command=$connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText=$query

#Creates a table in memory to be filled up with results from the query using ODAC
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$Adapter = New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter($command)

#Declaring variables for the loop
$fromrecord = 0
$numberofrecords = 1000000
$timesrun = 0

#Loop as long as the number of Rows in the virtual table are equal to specified $numberofrecords
while(($timesrun -eq 0) -or ($DataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count -eq $numberofrecords))
{
$DataSet.Clear()
$Adapter.Fill($DataSet,$fromrecord,$numberofrecords,'*') | Out-Null #Suppresses writing to console the number of rows filled
Write-progress "Saved: $fromrecord Rows"
$DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-Csv $output -Append -NoTypeInformation
$fromrecord=$fromrecord+$numberofrecords
$timesrun++
}

$connection.Close()
```

Answer (score 2):

In the *nix community we love one-liners!

**You can set markup to 'csv on' in sqlplus (>= 12)**

Create the query file

```
cat > query.sql <<EOF
set head off
set feed off
set timing off
set trimspool on
set term off
spool output.csv
select 
  object_id, 
  owner, 
  object_name, 
  object_type, 
  status, 
  created, 
  last_ddl_time 
from dba_objects;
spool off
exit;
EOF
```

Spool the *output.csv* like this:

```
sqlplus -s -m "CSV ON DELIM ',' QUOTE ON" user/password@\"localhost:1521/<my_service>\" @query.sql
```

**Another option is SQLcl** (the SQL Developer CLI tool. Binary name: *'sql'* renamed by me to *'sqlcl'*)

Create the query file (Note! term on|off)

```
cat > query.sql <<EOF
set head off
set feed off
set timing off
set term off
set trimspool on
set sqlformat csv
spool output.csv
select 
  object_id, 
  owner, 
  object_name, 
  object_type, 
  status, 
  created, 
  last_ddl_time 
from dba_objects 
where rownum < 5;
spool off
exit;
EOF
```

Spool the *output.csv* like this:

```
sqlcl -s system/oracle@\"localhost:1521/XEPDB1\" @query.sql
```

Viola!

```
cat output.csv 
9,"SYS","I_FILE#_BLOCK#","INDEX","VALID",18.10.2018 07:49:04,18.10.2018 07:49:04
38,"SYS","I_OBJ3","INDEX","VALID",18.10.2018 07:49:04,18.10.2018 07:49:04
45,"SYS","I_TS1","INDEX","VALID",18.10.2018 07:49:04,18.10.2018 07:49:04
51,"SYS","I_CON1","INDEX","VALID",18.10.2018 07:49:04,18.10.2018 07:49:04
```

**And the winner is sqlplus for 77k rows! (removed filter rownum < 5)**

```
time sqlcl -s system/oracle@\"localhost:1521/XEPDB1\" @query.sql

real    0m23.776s
user    0m39.542s
sys     0m1.293s

time sqlplus -s -m "CSV ON DELIM ',' QUOTE ON" system/oracle@localhost/XEPDB1 @query.sql

real    0m3.066s
user    0m0.700s
sys     0m0.265s

wc -l output.csv
77480 output.csv
```

**You can experiment with formats in SQL Developer.**

```
select /*CSV|HTML|JSON|TEXT|<TONSOFOTHERFORMATS>*/ from dba_objects;
```

**If you are loading CSV into the database, this tool will do it!**

https://github.com/csv2db/csv2db

Best of luck!

Comment: I tried the sqlplus method but it outputs the file in a very messed up format. The SQL Developer method cannot be scheduled to run on the virtual machine so not a solution...

Comment: @JarekSzczyg you probably need to "set" some more configuration settings like `linesize` and `pagesize`. I recommend reading the _SQL*Plus_ documentation for the Oracle version you are using.

Comment: @Abra is absolutely right. You need to add these instructions to the query script set pagesize 9999 and set linesize 200. The reason it's not in the query script is due to the fact I have configured sqlplus to load my login.sql on every startup where all my favorite settings are configured.

Comment: I did tried playing with these settings but I couldn't make "set sqlformat csv" work, I had to use /*csv*/ which for some reason wasn't always working. Also "SET TRIMSPOOL" did not work either which was saving the file with lots of white spaces. My 1.3 GB file would end up twice the size. I never used sql*plus and scripts in Oracle so it all seem a bit complicated for me.

Comment: I tried running it the way you specified and here's what it says: ```Error starting at line 1 in command:
cat > query.sql <<EOF
Error report:
Unknown Command
line 3: SQLPLUS Command Skipped: set feed off````

Comment: set trimspool on will make your file significantly smaller. You will have to adapt the *nix script to Windows Powershell or just use an editor of choise to create the query.sql file.

Comment: @BjarteBrandt I tried putting "set trimspool on" but when I run the script it just said "SQLPLUS Command Skipped: set trimspool off" as if that command doesn't exist. I have SQL*plus version 12.1.0.2.0 so I don't know what the problem was. Also, having the "spool file.csv" in the .sql file didn't do anything. It only worked in Oracle Developer.